# Graphql define variable as field

Tags: graphql

I'm querying a scheme that looks like this:

```
{
  collections {
    listings {
      tokenid
      price
    }
    tokens {
      id
      collection
    }
  }
}
```

How can I loop through the `tokens` field and get listings with the `tokenid`?

I imagine it looks something like this:

```
{
  collections {
    tokens {
      $id: id
      collection
      listings(where: {tokenid: $id}) {
        tokenid
        price
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the API supports introspection, you should be able to view the schema documentation and see how it works. You can try to use a GraphQL-capable client, like Insomnia or GraphiQL.

While the exact implementation might require a different structure, my guess will be something like this:

```
query($id: ID!) {
  collections {
    listings(tokenid: $id) {
      tokenid
      price
    }
  }
}
```

and you'll need to specify id as a parameter inside the client.